# Inno Setup : How to setup advance settings for IIS application pool?

Tags: iis, inno-setup, pascal

In Inno setup script how to set advance settings for IIS application pool? I'm specifically looking for setting Idle Time-out property?
I was not able to find and helpful information related to setting up IIS or deploying website [Inno Setup product help page](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php)

Here's screen capture of advance property from IIS :

[image: IIS application pool advance settings - Idle Time-out]

Following is a snippet of where I create application pool:

```
{Configure IIS website}
procedure ConfigureIISWebsite();
begin
  try
  AppPool.Stop();
  // Connect to the IIS server. 
  WebService := IIS.GetObject('IIsWebService', '{#IISServerName}' + '/w3svc');
  // Get the website. 
  WebServer := WebService.GetObject('IIsWebServer', '{#IISServerNumber}');
  WebRoot := WebServer.GetObject('IIsWebVirtualDir', 'Root');
  except
  end;
end;

{Configure App pool}
function ConfigureAppPool(): Boolean;
begin
   // Read values into variables
  Result := True;
  ApplicationName := InputAppNamePage.Values[0];
  VirtualDirectory := InputAppNamePage.Values[0];
  IISApplicationPoolName := InputAppNamePage.Values[0];
    // Create the application pool. 
    try
      AppPool := AppPools.Create('IIsApplicationPool', IISApplicationPoolName);
      AppPool.ManagedPipelineMode := '{#APPPOOL_MANAGED_PIPELINE_MODE}';
      AppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion :=   '';
      AppPool.SetInfo();
      ConfigureIISWebsite();
    except
      Log('Failed to create an application pool.');
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;     
  end;
end;
```

Would appreciate if someone can point me to any helpful resource or code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off suggestion from [@MartinPrikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) following is what worked for my use case :

```
AppPool.IdleTimeout := '0'; // 0 value means infinite
```

While exploring this I was also able to achieve same by using following ways :

**NOTE : Run installer with appropriate administrative privileges.**

**1) Using [Registry] section :**

```
    [Registry]
    ; Modify Idle Time-out for an IIS application pool
    Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS\{IIS Version}\AppPools\{YourAppPoolName}"; ValueType: dword; ValueName: "IdleTimeout"; ValueData: {time in seconds}
```

Replace the following placeholders with appropriate values:

- {IIS Version}: The version of IIS you are targeting (e.g., "7.0" for IIS 7, "10.0" for IIS 10).
- {YourAppPoolName}: The name of the IIS application pool you want to modify.
- {time in seconds}: The desired idle timeout value in seconds (e.g., 1800 for 30 minutes).

**2) Using [Run] section :**

```
   [Run]
   Filename:{sys}\inetsrv\appcmd.exe; Parameters:"set apppool /apppool.name:YourAppPoolName /processModel.idleTimeout:00:30:00"; Flags: runhidden
```

Replace the following placeholders with appropriate values:

- YourAppPoolName: The name of the IIS application pool you want to modify.
- 00:30:00: The desired idle timeout value in seconds (e.g., 1800 for 30 minutes).

Hope this helps others in future.